# How can I apply a vertical alignment to a UIBarButtonItem in Swift

Tags: swift, vertical-alignment, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a *UIToolbar* that contains several *UIBarButtonItem* s, of different font sizes.  All the items seems to be aligned to a certain one baseline.  Depending on the height of the toolbar, a specific font size tends to appear in the vertical center.  But the other items of off-center.  How can I set these other items to appear in the vertical center?

Note: The items are all text - no images.
Many other responses are very old and/or are only for images.  Most obj.c functions/methods are easily converted to Swift.

I place the items using:

```
func addLabel(_ text: String, textcolor: UIColor?, font: UIFont?, items: inout [UIBarButtonItem], verticalOffset: CGFloat) -> Int {
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(title: text, style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    if font != nil {
        item.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : font!], for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
    if textcolor != nil {
        item.tintColor = textcolor!
    }
    items.append(item)
    return items.count-1
}
```

I've tried (these won't work):

- *setTitleTextAttributes* with .baselineOffset
- *setTitlePositionAdjustment*
- *setBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment*
- `let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: itemView)` where itemView is a *UIView*

Perhaps the last one where I wrap a UILabel in a view, then set the item as customView may work but for me it showed all over the place. I tried replacing the main method content with:

```
    let itemView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: verticalOffset, width: 0, height: 0))
    let itemText = UILabel()
    itemText.text = text
    itemText.textColor = textcolor
    itemText.font = font
    itemText.sizeToFit()
    itemView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: itemView)
    itemView.addSubview(itemText)
```

**How can I offset some items on a toolbar?**

Answer (score 0):

Well I was close.  *I was able to get around this problem by wrapping each label in a view and setting it as a custom view*.  Then I added `itemText.center.y = self.center.y - verticalOffset`.  But the labels aligned their vertical center to the base of the toolbar - well on mine at least.  So I set the offsets to half the toolbar height.  They appear in the toolbar's vertical center!  (Also I had to adjust some horizontal spacing by appending some fixed width UIBarButtonItem s.)

After that I had some difficulty to access the items - only for a short while.  I managed to change the labels by using `(items![abc].customView!.subviews[0] as! UILabel).text = "xyz"`.  **Hiding** items was easy: `items![abc].customView?.alpha = 0` - setting 1 for **Showing**.